# Is it possible to style javascript popup box?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi im using this kind of popup box on my website. I was wodnering if its possible to style it with css. If not can anyone give a simple popup box that you can style where i can present the same information? Thanks!

code:

```
document.getElementById("contact").onclick = function(e) { // bind the event 
click.
e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default behavior 
alert('' + this.innerText + '\n\nPhone number: 6403334444\n\nEmail: 
dradcliff15@gmail.com');
}
```

Comment: The alert box is provided by the system, and not subject to CSS styles. You can make an HTML element that is hidden and gets shown in your click handler

Comment: take a look at the [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element